# Return UDT from postgresql function as single parameter

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-types

I am trying to write a function that returns a record consisting of a single column of a user defined type so that I can ingest them in java using the `ResultSet.getObject(int colNumber, Class<T> class)` method. If my function returns more than one column it works as expected, but if my function has just the one column then it expands the UDT back out into its constiuent parts so that I cannot use the desired method. e.g.

```
create type test as (x int, y int);

create or replace function test()
returns table(test test)
as $$
    select (42, 7)::test;
$$ language sql;

create or replace function test2()
returns table(test test, junk boolean)
as $$
    select (42, 7)::test, false;
$$ language sql;
```

Running `test2()` gives me data in the format I can ingest via the desired method but `test()` does not. How can I specify the return value of test to have the desired result?

```
postgres=# select * from test2();
  test  | junk 
--------+------
 (42,7) | f
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from test();
 x  | y 
----+---
 42 | 7
(1 row)
```

What I want is ...

```
postgres=# select * from test();
  test   
--------
 (42,7)
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think * is the problem. We use star for each column.

```
select test()
```

use this.

Comment: No, the function is declared as `returns table`  and therefor `select * from ...` is the correct way.

Comment: Well, this does exactly what I want. Thank you.

Comment: But I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name that using star should be the correct way, but it isn't. So maybe this is just a never found fault in postgres?

Comment: Because if I run "select test2()" I get a single column result of "("(42,7)",f)" which is *not* what I want in that case. Therefore, I have to know if my function returns a single value or multiple values to know how to call the function. That seems like a problem.